# Junit spring autowiring error

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I'm working through the book Spring in Action 4 but am having some trouble with spring's autowiring feature. The error i'm getting is

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

I think my issue is with getting the CDPlayerConfig class in the Test.java when I use the @ContextConfiguration annotation.

My interface:

```
package soundsystem;

public interface CompactDisk {
    void play();
}
```

My object:

```
package soundsystem;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SgtPeppers implements CompactDisk {
    private String title = "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band";
    private String artist = "The Beatles";

    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Playing " + title + " by " + artist);
    }
}
```

My configuration:

```
package soundsystem;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CDPlayerConfig {}
```

My JUnit Test:

```
package soundsystem;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=CDPlayerConfig.class)
public class CDPlayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisk cd;

    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(cd);
    }
}
```

I'm using JUnit 3.8.1 and Spring 4.1.4.RELEASE. This is only my second time ever using spring and I am at a loss, any help would be appreciated. This is also a maven project

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3067)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1817)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:41)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 30 more
```

Comment: *Which* class not found? You'll need to include the whole error message/stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using annotated configuration, the support is provided from 3.1 version onwards. You need to `AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class` in order to do it. So try doing the below. you can also do the configuration using inner class in which case Spring will load automatically. Please refer to this [article](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles) for further info.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=OrderServiceConfig.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest **SpringTestContext** for Maven

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test/4.2.0.RELEASE

It will solve the problem. 
Cheers!!!